# How to close an HTTP connection (which uses keep alive) from within a web application or a web service when there is no http request

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, http, tcp, connection

I am writing a proxy application that runs on IIS 7.5 (could be a WCF web service or an MVC application) which forwards some data to another process on another server which doesn't run on IIS.

This following is the situation, where S1 is the server where the proxy must forward the data to and C1 is the client:

S1 --A-- [proxy] --B-- C1

The need for the proxy application is because we want to secure the connection A with 2-way SSL. And this can easily be configured in IIS.
Because of the 2-way SSL we want to use the keep alive option of HTTP 1.1.
If connection A is closed, the proxy needs to close connection B and vice versa. Connection A can also be closed after some time out after the last response has been sent.

My question is:

**How can I close connection B after connection A is closed?**

So in other words let the proxy send a TCP FIN to C1.

For the proxy application I can either use an asp.net MVC web site or a WCF web service.
The problem is that the response has already been sent to the client and there is no 'current http request' between C1 and the proxy, when connection A is closed after a timeout. So a call like this: `HttpContext.Current.Response.Close()` does not close connection B.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you read EOS from the upstream socket, shutdown the downstream socket for output, and vice versa. When you do this, if you've already shutdown the socket that you read the EOS from, you've had EOS in both directions so you can close both sockets, and exit both threads if you're using threads. Let the actual decision as to when to close connections be taken by the downstream client and the upstream server.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But how can this be done programatically? I am not using sockets myself, the framework (MVC or WCF) handles this for me. So, for as far as I know, I have no control of these sockets. How do I find the connection that is used between the client and the proxy (there is no 'current http request' when connection A gets closed after a timeout). And  next, which method must be called to close it?

Comment: Your questions don't make sense. You're writing the proxy. You know when EOS occurs on either the upstream or the downstream socket. And don't tell me you're seriously asking me how to close a socket.